# How to check if an entity exists in DB using methods from SimpleJpaRepository

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to find out if any entity exists matching a few conditions using methods available in [SimpleJpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html).

My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private TaskEntity taskEntity;

    @Column
    private String name;

    ...
```

And my method looks like this:

```
/** Check if any entity exists with the given taskId and name */ 
public boolean existsByTaskAndName(int taskId, String name){
    MyEntity probe = new MyEntity();
        
    probe.setTask(entityManager.getReference(TaskEntity.class, taskId));
    probe.setName(name);

    return exists(Example.of(probe, ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnoreCase()));
}
```

I was expecting the sql query to look something like this:

```
select top 1 * from my_entity where task=@taskId and lower(name)=lower(@name)
```

But in reality, the SQL query contained inner joins with TaskEntity and all entities related to TaskEntity, and the where clauses contained comparison between all fields from TaskEntity and all fields from all other related entities. (in total 10+ inner joins and 100+ where clauses).

How can I write the method so that it only compares the columns "task" and "name", without any joins and without reading unnecessary objects?

Comment: With a native query. JPA is for objects, and any time you expect a certain SQL query to result from a particular JPA query, you'll most likely be disappointed.

Comment: @Kayaman, I understand. I don't want a certain SQL query, but surely there is a way to use JPA to check if any record already exists having 2 specific values. I updated the question a little bit

Comment: Sure there are ways. But then JPA creates the object graph with the joins and additional selects that you don't want. Because that's the automation it provides to "help" you. So no, you won't be able to do it easily without all those "unecessary" objects, because they're not unnecessary for JPA. They're unnecessary for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a JPQL Query like this:

```
select case when (count(*) > 0)  then true else false end from MyEntity m where m.taskEntity.id = :id and upper(m.name) = upper(:name)
```

It would return you a nice boolean.